# In Angular 2 'router-outlet' is not a known element

Tags: angular

I saw already a similar question about  'router-outlet'  in Stack Overflow but the response did not help me.

These are my modules, they do not give any error in Webclipse

nav.component.ts

```
import { RoutingModule } from '../routing/routing.module';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-nav',
templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})

@NgModule ({
imports: [
    RoutingModule,
]
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
constructor() { }
ngOnInit() {
}
}
```

nav.component.html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li>
      <a routerLink="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a routerLink="services">Services</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

routing.module.ts:

```
import { ChservicesComponent } from '../chservices/chservices.component';
import { HomeComponent } from '../home/home.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: 'services', component: ChservicesComponent},
];

@NgModule({
imports: [
 RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
],
exports: [
RouterModule
],
declarations: []
})
export class RoutingModule { }
```

The starting module  app.component.html:

```
 <app-nav></app-nav>
```

Comment: You can't have an `@NgModule` decorator on the same class as `@Component`. These are separate things. Have a separate "Module" class and include your "component" within the `declarations` array. In most basic configuration `AppModule`, `RoutingModule`, `Component`. All separate classes

Comment: I have a separate Module class: routing.module.ts.  Did not work from the beginning.  Then I added NgModule to Component (it is what you see) - did not help either

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be missing the point of the basic setup here. `@NgModule` and `@Component` are separate things, and the building blocks of your application structure.

An `@NgModule` is an "organizational" block. Where it's purpose is to share resources between grouped things. So generally speaking this is what allows you to use `declarations` to allow other components to use others.

The other is the `imports` array, for which the only valid things must themselves be `@NgModule`. Anything from `imports`that is similarly "exported" via it's own `exports` array property (such as other components).

That's the basic principles, and `<router-outlet>` is just another `@Component`, which happens to live in the `exports` property of `RouterModule`.

So however you have things organized, that `RouterModule` has to be a "localized export" of the present `@NgModule` scope encapsulating the current component. Sounds a mouthful, but it's actually pretty simple:

---

### Most Basic Setup

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { NavComponent } from './nav.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,             // nav is used from app
    NavComponent,              // router-outlet used in here
    // Any additional local components
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule          // router-outlet imported
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

// any additional component imports

const routes: Routes = [
   // route declarations and component mounts
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]            // router-outlet exported
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

---

## Feature Module Setup

Much the same but watch for the changes:

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { NavComponent } from './nav.component';
import { FeatureModule } from './feature.module'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,             // nav is used from app
    NavComponent,             // router-outlet used in here
    // Any additional local components
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,         // router-outlet imported
    FeatureModule             // <-- Import only for "static" load and not "lazy"
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

// any additional component imports

const routes: Routes = [
   // route declarations and component mounts
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]            // router-outlet exported
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**feature.module.ts**

```js
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { FeatureComponent } from './feature.component';
import { FeatureRoutingModule } from './feature-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FeatureComponent,
    // any components in the feature
  ],        
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FeatureRoutingModule    // <-- each feature "should" control it's own routes
  ]
})
export class FeatureModule { }
```

**feature-routing.module**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { FeatureComponent } from './feature.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'feature',
    component: FeatureComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],  // .forChild() injects to existing provider
  exports: [RouterModule]        // <-- allows "local" componets to use routerLink etc
})
export class FeatureRoutingModule { }
```

---

Those basically represent your use cases, with everything else being a slight variation off of that. But is you generally follow the structure then you cannot go wrong.

Comment: I changed to the basic setup and I am still getting the same problem.  Can you please add HTML files?